# Writing data read from Excel with Spout fails

Tags: php, excel

I'm reading an excelsheet with Spout and directly writing this data to a sheet results in a error.

```
Trying to add a value with an unsupported type: object in vendor/box/spout/src/Spout/Writer/XLSX/Internal/Worksheet.php on line 231
```

Does anybody have the solution?

```
$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
$reader->open($sFileNameExcel);

$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
$writer->openToFile($sWritePath.$sWriteFileName);

foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) 
{
    if ($sheet->getName()=='mysheet')
    {
        foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) 
        {
            $writer->addRow($row);
        }
    }
}

$writer->close();
$reader->close();
```

My data consists of string, integer and double fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sheet you're reading probably contains a date. The writer can't interpret dates though, hence the error.

Try configuring your reader this way: `$reader->setShouldFormatDates(true);` before calling `open`

Comment: Yes my sheet contains dates, these are the double values. Adding the 'setShouldFormatDates' setting did the trick! Thanks!!